# How is é bitwise shifted to a E in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, accent-sensitive

Hello I having trouble understanding this and how for example it take an accent char like `é` and converts it `E9`. I could be missing something i get that it bit-shifts right 4. `é = 11101000` and `E = 01000101` shifting 4 doesn't make`E` right?

```
static const char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
unsigned char ch;
*dest++ = digits[(ch >> 4) & 0x0F];//this returns E
*dest++ = digits[ch & 0x0F];//this returns 9
```

Comment: Explain, please, what do you want to achieve

Comment: Binary `11101000` shifted left by 4 bits is binary `1110`, or decimal 14. The string `digits` happens to have a character `E` at index 14.

Comment: You seem to be confusing ascii-representations with hex values. `digits[('é'>>4)&0x0F]` is simply the 14th value in your `digits` array, which is `E`. It has nothing to do with the ascii-representation of `"E"`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks

Comment: `é = 11101000` Note that this is only true in your specific character encoding. It is not true in UTF-8 or any other Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't convert `é` to `E9` - it converts an 8-bit number to its hexadecimal representation, in four-bit pieces ("nybbles").

`digits[(ch >> 4) & 0x0F]` is the digit that represents the high nybble, and `digits[ch & 0x0F]` is the digit that represents the low nybble.

If you see `é` become `E9`, it's because `é` has the value 233 in your character encoding.